# how read table know schema?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm new to scala, and seeing one code

```
val myDF = sparkSession.read.table("tableName")
val newDF = myDF.filter(col("id") == 10)
```

here `tableName` is S3 bucket, I've gone through everywhere, but didnt find any schema. Then how come `myDF.filter` is able to use id col name ?

Does it pick schema automatically while reading `tableName` ? seems strange to me, usually what I've seen so far is passing schema structure or setting parameter yes to pick header as a schema is used.

May I know please how its taking schema too and able to filer on `id` basis ?

Comment: You can specify the option to consider first row as column if the file in that S3 location has header in it.
Ex: val myDF = sparkSession.read.option("header", true).table("tableName")

Comment: @SrikanthKantamaneni, if its not specified then how its picking column names ?

Comment: You need to mention header as true if you are reading a file. If you are reading a table, the schema is appended to the table itself. File may or may not have column names but table will have column names. We can't create a table without column names.